# Alignment Issue With Ext JS 4 and fieldcontainer position

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a window, a panel (fill whole space of window) inside this window and inside panel two `fieldcontainers` horizontally on the left and on the right side.

```
----------------------------
|            |             |
|            |             |
|  left FC   |  right FC   |
|            |             |
|            |             |
|            |             |
----------------------------
```

Both could be hidden in runtime but, when I set `FC_left.Visible(false)` right `fieldcontainer` border isn't on the left side of the window but there's a large margin between left window border and left (this right `fieldcontainer`) container border. Something like this:

```
----------------------------
|     |                    |
|     |                    |
|     |      right FC      |
|     |                    |
|     |                    |
|     |                    |
----------------------------
```

When left containner is invisible I want to see right container on the place of left. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be provide [`flex:1`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Box-cfg-flex) or [`width:'50%'`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer-cfg-width) to your [`fieldcontainer`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer).

Here in this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2eun)**, I have created a demo using `panel` and `fieldcontainer`. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        /*
         * this function will fire when hide/show button clicked
         * @param {Ext.button.Button}
         */
        function onHideShow(btn) {

            var fCnt = btn.up('panel').down(`#${btn.label}`);

            if (fCnt.isHidden()) {
                fCnt.setVisible(true);
                btn.setText(`Hide ${btn.label}`);
            } else {
                fCnt.setVisible(false);
                btn.setText(`Show ${btn.label}`);
            }
        }

        //Create panel with field container
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {

            title: 'Basic example',

            //height:400,

            layout: 'hbox',

            bodyPadding: 10,

            defaults: {
                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',

                flex: 1,

                //width:'50%',

                style: 'border: 2px solid #ccc;',

                labelAlign: 'top',
                // The body area will contain three text fields, arranged
                // horizontally, separated by draggable splitters.
                layout: 'vbox',
                defaults: {
                    width: '100%',
                    margin: '5 10'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    xtype: 'splitter'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    xtype: 'splitter'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1
                }]
            },

            items: [{
                itemId: 'Left',
                fieldLabel: 'Left field container',
                margin: '0 5'
            }, {
                itemId: 'Right',
                fieldLabel: 'Right field container'
            }],

            tbar: ['->', {
                text: 'Hide Left',
                label: 'Left',
                handler: onHideShow
            }, {
                text: 'Hide Right',
                label: 'Right',
                handler: onHideShow
            }],

            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```